# Is it possible to use numeric ranges larger than Int.MaxValue in Scala 3.2?

Tags: scala, types, lazy-evaluation

I'm writing a piece of code in Scala which folds over this range:

```
(BigInt("0") until BigInt("1000000000000")).foldLeft(...)(...)
```

The code itself runs perfectly if I make the range smaller, but the program execution ends with exit code 0 without even executing any of the operations within FoldLeft.

When I try some additional examples, these are the results:

```
val range1 = (BigInt("0") until BigInt("1000000000000"))
println(range1(take(1)))

Result: No output, Process finished with exit code 0
```

```
val range2 (BigInt("0") until BigInt("1000"))
println(range2(take(1)))

Result: NumericRange 0 to 0, Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see, the range glitches out even if it doesn't ever evaluate the upper bound of the range. How can this happen? Numeric Ranges appear to be defined in the documentation as being valid, but as soon as they are actually used they glitch out.

Furthermore, in debug mode (IntelliJ) `range1` throws an IllegalArgumentException when it is examined in-memory, because its size cannot be evaluated. When I check the documentation it seems this is correct, as the size of NumericRanges is definied by an Int.

Does this mean numeric ranges are basically impossible to use on large ranges in Scala?

TL;DR
Tried: iterating over Scala ranges using the `until` and `to` keywords, using the datatypes `long` and `BigInt`, with the size of the range larger than Int.MaxValue
Expected: able to iterate over numeric ranges
Result: program terminates unexpectedly

EDIT: Additional context, I'm having trouble with getting Scala to throw exceptions in general. I'm not sure if this is a scala problem or an intellij problem at the moment.

Comment: What is `take` method in your examples? What does it return?

Comment: That being said, your output is probably misleading and you should get an exception like _java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than Int.MaxValue elements_. So, no ranges cannot contain more than max_int items but the max value of the range can be larger though.

Comment: If you give us more context on what you want to achieve, we might be able to give you alternatives to the usage of `Range`s.

Comment: **Scastie** reproducing the problem: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/J36g8PSjTuy0i284aMMw1A/1 - I would say this is a bug, worth checking if there is an existing report otherwise open a new report: https://github.com/scala/bug

Comment: If you are just looking for a way to iterate over a large range, try `Iterator.iterate(BigInt("0")) { _ + 1 }.takeWhile(_ < BigInt("1000000000000"))` ... Otherwise, yeah, looks like you found a scala bug. FWIW, doesn't seem to work very well with scala 2.13 either.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a bug of scala collection library (`NumericRange`). Just to explain what happens, when you try to take some amount of values in a range, the API is designed to check if the amount of elements in the new range are more than `Int.MaxValue`, then it throws the exception. Here:

```scala
// ...
val limit = num.fromInt(Int.MaxValue)
// ...
if (num.gt(t, limit)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("More than Int.MaxValue elements.")
else t
// ...
```

But the same exact thing is not checked when you're actually creating new ranges, and that's unpredictable for the developers.

Comment: You mean the bug is that is doesn't throw when the range is created? But still you wouldn't be able to create ranges with that many values.

Comment: OP or @AminMal, if you open the bug, could you please share the link here :)

Comment: @GaëlJ No I meant that the take method should not care about the length of the current range. What makes it unpredictable is the fact that you can create a wide range, but you can’t take a small amount of it somehow :)

Comment: @GaëlJ yeah sure, I was actually waiting for the OP to open the issue, might as well open it myself in a few minutes. I’ll let you know!

Comment: @GaëlJ here you are: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/12706